# How to show a pop up in Android and still be able to click on fragment

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-popupwindow

I'm trying to create a pop up that will notify the user if they got the correct answer, the user can then click the continue button to the next question. The pic below from the Duolingo app shows exactly what I want.

[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]

What class can be used to do this?

Comment: Make it as an Invisible view that will be shown after used did an action. You should be able to add transition animation too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`PopupWindow`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) class. It does exactly what you want. That's what has been used in the screenshot you posted above.

Here's an example: [How to Implement Popup Window in Android](http://mrbool.com/how-to-implement-popup-window-in-android/28285).

Comment: Thanks, i tried invisible method because i didnt see your answer right away and it worked pretty well, i will try PopupWindow next i didnt know about that either. Thank you.